# Trying to fetch data from database error 

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

This is the script. I am getting an error on line 29 which is..

```
$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);
```

(Compare as well this question [PHP error: Warning: ociparse() expects parameter 2 to be string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441861/php-error-warning-ociparse-expects-parameter-2-to-be-string))

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

<?php

/* Set oracle user login and password info */
$dbuser = "sjsrem"; /* your deakin login */
$dbpass = "shaz"; /* your oracle access password */
$db = "SSID";
$connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

if (!$connect) {
echo "An error occurred connecting to the database";
exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM purchase";
$query = OCIParse($connect, $sql);
OCIExecute($query);

/* check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them */
$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);
//echo "SQL: $query<br>";
if(!$stmt) {
echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
exit;
}
OCIExecute($stmt);?>




<!-- Now we output the data using a table and/or formatted HTML -->




<table>
<?PHP while (OCIFetch($query)) {

   $fg1 = OCIResult ($query , "ID" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>id: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg2 = OCIResult ($query , "FNAME" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>name</td><td>");  echo ($fg2);    echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg3 = OCIResult ($query , "LNAME" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>email: </td><td>");    echo ($fg3);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg4 = OCIResult ($query , "VIN" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Vin: </td><td>");    echo ($fg4);    echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg5 = OCIResult ($query , "EMAIL" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Email: </td><td>");   echo ($fg5);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg6 = OCIResult ($query , "UNIT" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Unit: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg7 = OCIResult ($query , "STREET" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Street: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg8 = OCIResult ($query , "SUBURB" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Suburb: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg9 = OCIResult ($query , "PCODE" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Post Code: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg10 = OCIResult ($query , "CREDIT" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Credit: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg11 = OCIResult ($query , "HOLDER" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Holder: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg12 = OCIResult ($query , "EXPIRY" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Expiry: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");


   }  



   ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would probably also be useful to show us "line 50" separately... not sure about others, but I'm not going to count! Also, what's in `$query`?

Comment: Sorry:
Line 50 : <?PHP while (OCIFetch($query)) {


error : ?>
Warning: ocifetch() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/sjrem/public_html/SIT104_3/order.php on line 50

Comment: Where do you define `$query`?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter must be a resource but you are passing sql string. In your code resource is `$stmt`. You need to use `$stmt` instead of `$query`

```
OCIFetch($stmt)
```

Also for `OCIResult` again you need to use `OCIResult($stmt)` not `OCIResult($query)`

Comment: I realised i hadn't put select * from purchase.

Now i am getting an error on line 30 : $stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);

error: Warning: ociparse() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in /home/sjrem/public_html/SIT104_3/order.php on line 30
An error occurred in parsing the sql string.

Comment: Can you put the whole `$query` line here please.