# PHP error: Warning: ociparse() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php

Getting this error when trying to display data from the database.

```
Warning: ociparse() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in /home/sjrem/public_html/SIT104_3/order.php on line 29
An error occurred in parsing the sql string.
```

line 29 : `$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);`

Comment: What's in `$query`? `var_dump($query)`.

Comment: $query = OCIParse($connect, $sql);
OCIExecute($query);

Comment: Why do you expect `$query` being a string?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're providing a database resource to [`oci_parse` <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php), but it expects a string as second parameter.

That's merely a description why you get the error (a bit lengthy for a comment), not how you can solve that.

Given the code you've provided in your comment:

```
OCIParse($connect, $sql);
OCIExecute($query);
```

You pass `$sql` as second parameter to `oci_parse` which should be fine assuming it's a string.

**Note:** `OCIParse` could be written as `ociparse` which both are an alias to `oci_parse`.